# Facebook “like” button shows count of homepage instead specific article

Tags: facebook

I have a website with a news section, and want to put individual "like" buttons in each post. The problem is that some buttons shows the root like count and not the count of that specific page/post.

The weirdest is that it works in one of the pages, but not in the others.

For example, a page with the incorrect count, that reverts to the root page:
http://lounge.obviousmag.org/apaixonadamente_curiosa/2012/10/arte-na-ponta-dos-dedos.html

Another page, with the correct count and URL:
http://lounge.obviousmag.org/embriaguez_artistica/2012/10/reflexao-fotografia-e-influencias.html

The code in the page is the same, so I don't have a clue of what I'm doing wrong.

Any Guesses?